# Bash function get current command line

Tags: bash

I often do something like this:

```
tail -f logs/`ls -rt logs | tail -1`/debug.log
```

I would like to have a macro for `ls -rt <some_dir> | tail -1`, but it needs to work in the context of the current command line (`<some_dir>` being pulled from the current command line).  Is there a way to do that?

Something like:

```
tail -f logs/$(LAST)/debug.log
```

Comment: So, I don't know how to get the current command line context outside of a bash completion function.  Corrected my question to add "logs" in the ls -rt command to make this more clear.

Comment: And writing a script named (perhaps) `taild` that takes the directory name as an argument and then executes: `tail -f logs/$(ls -rt "$1" | tail -1)/debug.log` isn't an acceptable solution?

Comment: Yes, it's the only thing I've thought of.  I just hit kind of a wall in my knowledge of bash and wanted to see if there was something out there I didn't know about.  Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not tied to determining `<some_dir>` within a sub-command, you can achieve the same effect with...

```
tail -f `ls -drt logs/* | tail -1`/debug.log
```

The `-d` causes `ls` to include full paths of matches, but you need the trailing `/*` so that it returns the *files* within the directory instead of the directory itself.

Comment: or even `ls -drt logs/*/debug.log | tail -1` inside the subshell. either way. well, that simplifies the command line, thanks!  I'll accept this for now as it appears there is no way to do *exactly*  what I was asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Using `$0` will get you the current command and `$*` will get the parameters.  Try `echo $0 $*` to see if that helps.  Obviously you can assign those to other variable if necessary.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortuately this doesn't really help the case I'm looking for.  `echo foo bar | echo $0 $*` prints *bash* (the $0 of the invoked shell, not of my current command line)